# In objective-c, is there some way to check a variable hasn't been released by the time a lambda is called?

Tags: objective-c, lambda, objective-c-blocks

In objective-c, is there some way to check a variable hasn't been released by the time a lambda is called?

```
-(void) loadImageIntoImageView:(UIImageView*) imgView
{
    [MyLibrary getImageFromWebSlowly complete:^(UIImage *img, BOOL success) {
        // What if this bit of code is called 50 seconds later,
        // and by that time the imgView was dealloc'd or released?
        // Eg by that time the user closed the view with the image view on it.
        imgView.image = img;
    }];
}
```

Any suggestions?

(edited for clarity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, don't use `__block` or, more complexly, assign `nil` to the `__block` variable when it is deallocated.

As written, there is no need for the `__block` keyword in that code *unless you explicitly want a weak reference to `imgView`* (which you probably don't).

Comment: You're right, i dont need __block, so i've removed it for clarity from the question (and my code), but my question still stands: what happens if in the intervening time, the user had closed that view and it had been dealloced? The block doesn't retain/release it automatically does it?

Comment: The block will retain any captured object references when the block is copied (which it will be in that code, assuming it is implemented correctly) and release them automatically when the block is released.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean "deallocated" rather than released, and with no garbage collection on iOS, this isn't possible.  You should use some other method to determine whether the `UIImageView` has gone away.

Also, I don't think `__block` does what you think it does; consider reading about how [block variables work](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of __block, i've removed it for clarity from the question, but my question still stands: what happens if in the intervening time, the user had closed that view and it had been dealloced? The block doesn't retain/release it automatically does it?